# Should a SNAPSHOT version be deployed to QA and Prod

Tags: java, maven, deployment, versioning

In our project, we are deploying the snapshots of our projects binaries to tomcat/lib directories. Generally, in pom its mentioned

```
<version>0.2.22-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

And jar files deployed on qa/dev environments are

```
my-project-0.2.22-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

We are facing some consistencies issues, like build not happened accurately, some code reflects and some not after build, sometimes its merged old+new code.

My question is, whether such problem can be because we are deploying snapshots version on the environment? Also Is this good practice to deploy snapshots onto the environment?

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer to this: Never put a SNAPSHOT to QA nor to PROD...if reach the point to deliver to someone else than a developer make releases...

Answer (score 0):

By convention, a snapshot version is an unreleased version. The idea being that before a release we have a SNAPSHOT and this SNAPSHOT represents what might become a release.

Here's a concrete example:

- `T1`: start the dev cycle for release 1.0
- `T2`: deploy and test the first 1.0-SNAPSHOT
- `T3`: deploy and test the second 1.0-SNAPSHOT
- `T4`: deploy and test the third 1.0-SNAPSHOT
- `T5`: get sign off on 1.0-SNAPSHOT
- `T6`: branch, update version to 1.0
- `T7`: deploy 1.0 to PROD
- `T8`: start the dev cycle for release 1.1
- ... repeat

This is, of course, a simplification but the key points are solid, namely;

- Before any release exists there is a SNAPSHOT version of that release
- The SNAPSHOT version of a Release `X` basically means `a developemnt version of X`
- As the development cycle progresses the SNAPSHOT versions should get closer and closer to the eventual RELEASE version
- Typically, SNAPSHOT versions only exist during development and a RELEASE version should not have any dependencies on SNAPSHOTs.
- SNAPSHOT versions can be updated whereas RELEASE versions are immutable. So, downloading 1.0-SNAPSHOT today could give you a different file to what you got when you downloaded 1.0-SNAPSHOT yesterday. Peeking under the Maven covers a little bit; when you install or deploy a `1.0-SNAPSHOT` Maven will expand that version to `1.0-yyyMMdd-HHmmSS-i` thereby creating a timestamp specific version of `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Depending on when you resolve that dependency you might get a different version of 1.0-SNAPSHOT. You can control the way Maven resolves a SNAPSHOT dependency using the `updatePolicy` on your repository configuration but the central point remains; you can never be **certain** what version you will get when you rely on a SNAPSHOT version. This is fine in dev (indeed it's often desired behaviour in dev) but this lack of reproducibility is dangerous in PROD.

I think the above should help to explain why you are encountering these issues:

> We are facing some consistencies issues, like build not happened accurately, some code reflects and some not after build

In general, SNAPSHOTs should be used in DEV only. In formal test environments (such as QA) and **definitely** in PROD you should not be deploying or relying on SNAPSHOT versions.

The need to stand over a build, to be able to say exactly what's in it is essential in PROD and formal test evns and release versions (since they are immutable-by-intent) are designed to give you confidence that what's in your build is what you intend to be in your build.

Comment: RELEASE version is immutable, but if test in QA environments find bugs, what should we do?

Comment: @WestFarmer release a **new** version.

Comment: When you say DEV do you mean local only or a remote test env (not "formal" I guess, but remote) as well?

Comment: DEV could be local or remote though if it is remote (or shared) then it would likely be ‘bleeding edge’ rather than official or formal.